# Laravel Passport Create APIToken undefind function createToken

Tags: php, laravel-passport

I am Having this error in my code
Undefined function 'App\Http\Controllers\api\createToken'.intelephense(1010)
i have done all the necessary imports needed to use passport so that i can generate apiTokens but it does not work for me 
i will really appreciate it if i can get some one to help me in fixing this error thanks in advance

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class authController extends Controller
{


public function signup(Request $request)
{
    //

    $rules=[
     'name'=>'required|max:55',
    'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
    'password'=>'required',
    // 'password_confirm'=>'required',
    ];

//    $valid = $request->validate($rules);

    $valid = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);

    if($valid->fails()){
        return response()->json(
            $valid->errors(),400
        );
    }else{
        $user = User::create($request->all());
        $accessToken = $user-createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['user'=>$user,'accessToken'=>$accessToken], 201);
    }






}


public function login()
{
    //
}


public function logout(Request $request)
{
    //
}


public function user(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->token()->revoke();        return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully logged out'
    ]);
}


public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}


public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys it was a typo in the code

```
    $user-createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

i left out the '>' character

```
    $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```